# Changes in regression model coefficients after updating R to v3

Tags: r, updating

I have a quite long Rstudio markdown (about 1000 lines of code), which among other things includes a GLM and StepAIC. After updating to R v3 I do not seem to be able to replicate the regression coefficients exactly. The general lines are intact though: model accuracy stays the same, stepwise selected variables are same also.

Can anyone tell me 1) if this behavior is normal (or maybe I am lost in my versions of the scripts) and 2) is that possible to see the list of what has been updated in the correct version of R.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/NEWS and if you use packages they usually have NEWS files, too. Normally available from their CRAN page. For your first question we would need more information regarding the differences. Of course, you could always install an older R version and test if you can reproduce your results with that.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, that is what is wanted to know.